# Is there any way to replicate/recreate Levels effect in Blender Shading Nodes?

Tags: image, texture-baking, normal-map, pbr

I'm trying to make a normal map generator in Blender and I need to add Levels-like node. I'm using this tutorial about generating normal map from four pictures (https://dreamlight.com/how-to-create-normal-maps-from-photographs/#Photoshop - Create the Normal Map Layers header) and I'm stuck in a step where I must put Levels to 128-255 range on a Top-Right layer.
Is there any way to reinvent Levels node in Blender Shading Nodes (Shading card)?

Images:
My node tree
[image: My node tree]

Results (TOP, looks okay) and normalmap preview
[image: Results (TOP, looks okay) and normalmap preview]

Results from Left-Bottom corner, looks bad!
[image: Results from Left-Bottom corner, looks bad!]

Answer (score 1):

You can get the same functionality with the *Color Ramp* node.

*Add > Converter > Color Ramp*

[image]

And because the *Color Ramp* node uses 0-1 value range, just multiply your value by `1 / 255`.
Like this:

[image]

You can technically also do this with RGB curves, they're just a different tool for doing the same thing.